# Why kinetic energy is omitted from the Boltzmann factor?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I am studying an example of application of Boltzmann's distribution [Concepts in Thermal Physics](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199562091.001.0001/acprof-9780199562091)  (specifically the example 4.4 p.43). It is stated that given an isothermal atmosphere, the probability of finding a particle at height $z$ is given by:

$$P(z) \propto \exp\left({\frac{-mgz}{kT}}\right)$$

What I can't understand is why the kinetic energy is omitted if the Boltzmann distribution is generally given as:

$$P(E) = \frac{1}{Z} \exp\left({\frac{-E}{kT}}\right)$$

where $E = K + V$. I tried to justify the first equation by trying to derive the marginal distribution $P(z)$. Here is what I did:

$$P(E) = \frac{1}{Z} \exp\left({\frac{-E}{kT}}\right)= \frac{1}{Z} \exp\left({\frac{-K}{kT}}\right) \cdot \exp\left({\frac{-V}{kT}}\right)$$

In order to simplify the calculations I assumed discrete energy levels for both kinetic and potential energy. Therefore, the marginal distribution $P(z)$ or $P(V)$ is given by:

$$\sum_i \frac{1}{Z}\exp\left({\frac{-V}{kT}}\right) \exp\left({\frac{-K_i}{kT}}\right)$$

Because any possible combination of $V_j$ and $K_i$ is possible the partition function can be written as:

$$Z = Z_K \cdot Z_V$$

therefore the above sum reduces to:

$$P(z) =\frac{1}{Z_V} \exp\left({\frac{-mgz}{kT}}\right)$$

Is my reasoning correct? What if the energy levels weren't discrete?

Comment: Kinetic energy term is not omitted in Boltzmann distribution. In kinetic theory of gases : $$ {\frac {1}{2}}m{\overline {v^{2}}}={\frac {3}{2}}k_{\mathrm {B} }T. $$, so you have it there already.

Comment: Does the kinetic energy depend on *where* the particle is?

Comment: @DanielSank I have assumed that kinetic energy depends just on velocity and potential on position. Can kinetic energy depends on position?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas That is why I asked the question. In the example, the Boltzmann factor contains just the potential energy (gravitational potential energy).

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas In this case the kinetic energy does not depend on position (kinetic energy depending on position is rather unusual), which is the point. As the kinetic energy doesn't depend on position, the probability of finding particles *at a given height* shouldn't involve the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting kinetic and potential energies:
$$
\begin{align}
p   &= \frac 1q e^{-\left(\frac{E_k}{kT}+\frac{E_p}{kT}\right)} \\
    &= \frac 1q e^{-\frac{E_k}{kT}-\frac{E_p}{kT}} \\
    &= \frac 1q \frac{~~e^{-\frac{E_k}{kT}}}{e^{\frac{E_p}{kT}}}
\end{align}
$$

Acknowledging that $E_k = 3/2~kT$, let's further to reduce equation to
$$
p
= \frac{1}{e^{3/2}q} e^{-\frac{E_p}{kT}}
= \frac1Q e^{-\frac{mgz}{kT}}
\, .$$

So, basically kinetic energy part is factored out into normalization factor $Q$. Yet, there's another kinetic energy term inside exponent denominator, so that decreasing molecular concentration due to greater potential energy can still be compensated with molecule higher average speeds, i.e. bigger gas temperature if any.

Comment: I can't understand why you substitute $E_k = 3/2 kT$ (the mean kinetic energy).

Comment: What other kinetic energy expression you would suggest if not the one offered by [kinetic theory of gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Temperature_and_kinetic_energy) ?

Comment: Anyways probability of finding particle at given $z$ is already a ratio between potential and kinetic energies. I.E. $$ \exp\left({\frac{-mgz}{kT}}\right) $$, can be re-stated as $$ \exp\left({-3/2\frac{E_p}{E_k}}\right) $$ by multiplying exponent numerator and denominator by 3/2.

Comment: The Boltzmann factor doesn't contain average energy that is what troubles me.

Comment: So according to you temperature of the system is not related with average kinetic energy of molecule at all?

Comment: I can not understand what justifies to replace $E_k$, a variable in Boltzmann distribution, with a constant $\langle E_K \rangle$. I am not saying that temperature is not related. If I am not mistaken, $\langle E_K \rangle = 3/2 kT$.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Then why you don't ask what justifies to replace $E_p$ with $mgz$ accordingly? Why it does not depend on exact particle? Boltzman distribution qualifies system overall, not some particles.

Comment: I am replacing potential energy with $mgz$ not with a constant value ($3/2 kT$).

Comment: Temperature is a variable, not constant and in general it may be function of height, i.e. $T=T(z)$ and also depend on local temperature variations due to air convection, etc. Unless atmosphere is assumed to be isothermal, as it seems to be the case as it's stated in your question, (but it's idealized either). Anyway, I don't see a problem with constant parameters. Constant temperature (isothermal atmosphere!) maps to constant average kinetic energy. No problems at all here.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas How do you simplify the expression :\begin{equation}
  \frac 1q \frac{~~e^{-\frac{E_k}{kT}}}{e^{\frac{E_p}{kT}}}
\end{equation} ? Do you integrate with respect to something?

Comment: After that, it's just simple $E_k = 3/2~kT$ substitution into the expression, no integration steps involved at this point.